# Add and remove class different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsap

So im currently learning jquery and a little bit of tweenlite for animations (I wanna keep it basic). So im currently building a portfolio grid but I wanna add on a click of an element that the other element is fading in (sliding from right it doesn't matter).

But I can't find a way to make it work that 1 element have 1 box to show and the other element have a different box to show without coping the code over and over and change a simple number everytime, there must be a way to make it work without going to repeat the code over and over.

I created a codepen to show where my struggles are.

I hope I'm pretty clear with describing this problem :)

HTML

```
  <div class="box">
    <div class="show">Show 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="removeit">
      <div class="bigshow">Bigshow 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="show">Show 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="removeit">
      <div class="bigshow">Bigshow 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:500px;
}

.box {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0 auto;
  float:left;
  margin-right:50px;
}

.bigbox {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index:100;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display:none;
  top:0;
  .removeit {
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
}

  .show {
    display:block;
  }
  .noscroll {
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Javascript

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    $(".bigbox").addClass("show");
    TweenLite.to($('.bigbox'), 0.5, {
        opacity:1,
        autoAlpha:1
    });
});

$(".removeit").click(function(){
    TweenLite.to($('.bigbox'), 0.5, {
        autoAlpha:0,
        opacity:0
    });
});
```

The codepen

http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/MwjOXP

Comment: You are worried about code repetitions in HTML? Don't see anything repeating in JavaScript? Elaborate a little more on that please?

Comment: okay, ehm you got in the HTML something like a box1 with content, when you click on that box1 there must a div show with some content (bigbox in html). but that is doable with the code I have. but now I want also have box 2 open the same way as box1, but since i targeted box1 in the javascript I need to copy the javascript and change box1 to box2 to do the same thing with box2. That seems pretty useless since you keep repeating the code. I can't find a way to create a line of code that does something like "box1 has linked bigbox1 (they open the same time) box2 is linked to bigbox2 (like that)

Comment: I hope this is a little bit more clear than what I wrote down upstairs there. :)

Comment: Sure. One way to go about it would be to find the common ground between **box** and **bigbox** and that would be the **index** number of them in each of their classes. So this way, you could get the clicked index of a **box**, and get the relevant **bigbox** by feeding this clicked index to it. Getting?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/

Comment: Ye, when I googled my problem (again) I found that also. I gave it already a try to modify it they way I like it, I understand how it works but only the transition is starting top left (?) and I can't find a way to let the fadeout transition working, I got currently this http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/MwjrgL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, I think it is possible by finding the common ground between **box** and **bigbox** and if we are to not modify HTML. That common ground should be the **index** value from their respective classes.

- So store a *clickedIndex* variable first, inside the click handler
  like so: `var clickedIndex=$('.box').index($(this));`.
- And then feed this *clickedIndex* to get a selective **bigbox** like so: `var
  bigbox=$(".bigbox").eq(clickedIndex);`.
- And finally, use this **bigbox** variable further to fade in or out.

Here is your modified JavaScript:

```
var bigbox = null;
var clickedIndex = -1;
var boxElements=$(".box");
var bigboxElements=$(".bigbox");
var removeItElements=$(".removeit");
boxElements.click(function() {
  clickedIndex = boxElements.index($(this));
  bigbox = bigboxElements.eq(clickedIndex);
  bigbox.addClass("show");
  TweenLite.to(bigbox, 0.5, {opacity: 1,autoAlpha: 1});
});

removeItElements.click(function() {
  clickedIndex = removeItElements.index($(this));
  bigbox = bigboxElements.eq(clickedIndex);
  TweenLite.to(bigbox, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0,opacity: 0});
});
```

The only problem with this approach is that it is very dependant on the order with which the HTML has been laid out.

Comment: Thats pretty clever, had to reread it a couple times to understand what it is doing. Thanks for this, definitely got experiment with it. Thanks men

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, there is an `onComplete` callback available in **TweenMax** for your problem with adding / removing classes *after* your animations are done. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: For now it is fine, im already happy it works and gonna try some things more with it. I will keep it in my mind, im on a big learning curve right now so maby in the future in becomes usefull :)