# How to show different images using .hover() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm gonna try to explain my issue:

I have span elements, each span element have text, when the user hovers it, it should displays an image next to the element, each image is different, I was trying to use jQuery `.hover()` function, but when I hover on the text it shows me the whole images.

How can I solve it?.

My HTML.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="text-center">
                <span class="displayImage">Azotea </span>
                <span class="displayImage">Nivel 8 </span>>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-lg-5 text-left">
    <img class="displayed" src="images/azotea-n9.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="displayed" src="images/test2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

My Code.

```
$(".displayImage").hover(function(){
    $(".displayed").show();
}, function () {
    $(".displayed").hide();
});
```

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could associate the span with a particular image via a data attribute and id.

```js
$(".displayImage").hover(function(){
    // $(this).attr('data-img') == 'azotea' or 'nivel8'
    // so we end up with $('#azotea').show(), for example.
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-img')).show();
}, function () {
  $('#' + $(this).attr('data-img')).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="text-center">
                <span class="displayImage" data-img='azotea'>Azotea </span>
                <span class="displayImage" data-img='nivel8'>Nivel 8 </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-lg-5 text-left">
    <img class="displayed" src="images/azotea-n9.jpg" alt="azotea" id="azotea">
    <img class="displayed" src="images/test2.jpg" alt="nivel 8" id="nivel8">
</div>
```

Comment: This works really good, but one more question before I set this as the right question, can you explain me a bit of the code please? Thank you so much!.

Comment: I added a data-img attribute to each of the spans. The value references a corresponding ID on the images. In the hover handler, we look up the data-img attribute on the hovered element and use that to construct the corresponding ID. So for example `data-img="azotea"` gets us `img#azotea`. I've added a comment to the js above that hopefully illuminates it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I try don´t change your html

https://jsfiddle.net/luarmr/hjreda3r/

I add a little css as well for hide the elements from the origin

```
$(".displayImage").hover(
    function(el){
        var image = $(this).data('ref');
        $(".displayed:nth-child(" + image + ")").show();
    }, function () {
        $(".displayed").hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to better use css3 instead of jquery, cos jquery slows down productivity of your site on mobile gadgets, so maybe you should look here [enter link description here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find common ground between your `span` & `image` and ***without*** adding anything extra in your markup, that would be the `index` value of each of them. Obviously, this solution that I recommend below is entirely dependant on the order with which you lay out your HTML.

Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382841/add-and-remove-class-different-elements/30384049#30384049) I posted for a similar problem.

So basically, your code should become something like this:

```js
$(".displayed").hide();
$(".displayImage").hover(function(){
  $(".displayed").eq($(this).index()).show();
},function(){
  $(".displayed").eq($(this).index()).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="text-center">
                <span class="displayImage">Azotea </span>
                <span class="displayImage">Nivel 8 </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-lg-5 text-left">
    <img class="displayed" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/Codepen/PIXI/0.4/images/JS.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="displayed" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45891870/Experiments/Codepen/PIXI/0.4/images/PIXI.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Hope it helps in some way.

T